# How can Chromium use XUL Runner SDK?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, xulrunner

In the credits section of Chromium and Chrome (chrome://credits/) you can find **XUL Runner SDK**.

I've done some search in the chromium website and didn't find any sign of it nor for what is it used.

I was trying to decide between using something like [chromiumembedded](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/), [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/), WebKit, XUL Runner, libRocket, etc. so that finding is confusing.

So my question is: Why is XUL Runner SDK in chrome://credits/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [search the source code](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/search?q=xulrunner) to check. The only actual use of the XULRunner SDK appears to be in `mock_ie_event_sink_test.h` where an accessibility-related file is being included. Constants from that file (like `IA2_EVENT_DOCUMENT_LOAD_COMPLETE`) are then being used in `mock_ie_event_sink_test.cc` - a unit test file. So the dependency on XULRunner doesn't seem to apply to any code actually shipping with Google Chrome.